# Too much data sent causes connection closed (Laravel Nova filter)?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, nginx

I'm writing a custom filter in Laravel Nova, and getting an `ERR:CONNECTION CLOSED` in the JavaScript console. Playing with it, it seems to happen when there's too much data in my options. 
Is there a setting somewhere I'm missing that closes the connection after a certain amount of data sent?

This is on nginx. I've tried mucking with the fastcgi_buffers and that seems to not be the problem.

Comment: Is the connection getting closed immediately, or does it take some time before it happens?

Comment: @Jason The connection is getting closed immediately.

Comment: Here's another weird clue: if I just refresh the page but send a bunch of data, it works. But if I open a new tab/browser, it doesn't. What would be the difference?